# How to display divs horizontally in line in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image of a map and then some javascript to allow zooming in when you hover on it, I want to display the zoomed in section on the right of the original image but it's currently appearing below it instead. I tried align=right but it's not actually an image it's a container so that didn't work. Here's my code;

```html
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="Images/Calderpark Shopping centre map.jpg" width="600">
  <hr><div id="myresult" align=right class="img-zoom-result"> </div></hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a span instead of a div or put the divs display to inline-block. Or just use the css grid system so you can position anything anywhere. HTML5 also offers you the <figure> and <figcaption> tags to use instead of divs if you want more semantic html.

Comment: Always give image width in percentage. example, width="50%"

Answer (score 1):

`align` attribute is **not supported in HTML5**, instead you can achieve the same using CSS.

Moreover, `div` is by default a **block** element. `align` attribute works only with `inline` elements.

`display: flex` is what you needed in CSS.

```css
.horizontal-container{
  display:flex;
}
.zoomed-map{
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-container">
  <div class='actual-map'>
    <img id="myimage" src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="200">
  </div>
  <div class='zoomed-map'>
    zoomed container
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-zoom-container {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="Images/Calderpark Shopping centre map.jpg" width="600">
  <div id="myresult" align=right class="img-zoom-result">hello </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle (solution attached here): https://jsfiddle.net/3uw7dnob/2/

You can give property "float:right" and I have given one example of left and right block. You can always have two block side by side by this trick.

```
.left-block {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.right-block {
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```